# Dominant speeds of Morse Communications

Tags: cw

5 wpm is easy to learn and better than nothing in emergency.
Speed Morse Coding is fine for "sport competition"

I am trying to find out which is the typical speed for what I call "conversation" and define it with the following questions:

- Are there statistics about the speed distribution?
- Which is the most common speed in wpm for contacts over words in exchange?
- Which is the most common speed in wpm for communication with duration over 5 min?
- Which is the average speed in wpm used for morse coding?
- Which is the median of the speed in wpm for mose coding?
- Which are the terciles or quartiles of the speed for morse coding?
- Is there a standard speed used by NATO, UN or any national military?
- Which is the standard speed for messages sent by machine?
- At which speed starts "speed coding"?

The reason for this question:
Using the Koch method you train with the "letter speed" farnsworth compression in wpm which you want to achieve at the end, while step by step decreasing spacing and errors. If you choose a too high speed you may never reach the standard spacing by an acceptable number of errors, if you choose a too low speed, it is difficult to increase your speed later. Therefore one should know which speed is mostly used for longer communication between people who are experienced in sending morse code.

Comment: hi! nice having you here, but please realize that you're really just asking for opinions, which is off-topic here. Obviously, everyone in here will have a different opinion on this topic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller is right. ['What is the best...' type questions are off-limits](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on any SE site. Your question already has two close votes and should be reworded so that it can be opened again.. But I agree that your 16 to 21 WPM is not a bad choice.

Comment: I sort of admire your question, and hopefully either you or someone else will come along and edit your question so that it can be opened again. I am sure that there is a way; sorry that I can't think of one right now.

Comment: I agree with Mike! If we can get something that someone else can factually answer, that would be cool!

Comment: @MarcusMüller (et al) How about something along the lines of "What CW speed range are the majority of CW ops using?" If a change something like that (or better) is made, then I would be more than happy to reopen it! :-)

Comment: Oh! That sounds nice. But: is there such data? At this point, we could basically change OP's question without OP's input without doing any more damage, but if we do that, I'd rather change it to something that has a chance of getting answered.

Comment: Why don't you do that, @MarcusMüller ? I'll likely reopen it if you (or anyone else) does. :-)

Comment: @MikeWaters done! I intentionally went a bit into breadth; as said, I have no idea what kind of data is available (publicly).

Comment: @MarcusMüller What do you think about the "Best" in the title?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94677/discussion-between-mike-waters-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: Your typing speed may also have a limiting effect.

Answer (score 11):

Data from the [Reverse Beacon Network](http://reversebeacon.net) provides an answer. RBN receivers and computers decode CW (and other "digital" modes) to identify stations calling CQ and posts information about signal strength and operating speed. I think it's reasonable to assume that QSOs are conducted at the same speed as the op sends "CQ."

Click on "DX Spots" followed by "Download Raw Data" to access files of "comma separated values" (.csv) for specific dates. For example, I downloaded 20190210.csv, a Saturday, from which I calculated an average CW speed of 24.6WPM. Performing the same analysis for 20181124 - the first day of the annual CQ WW CW contest - results in an average CW speed of 31.7WPM, a nearly 30% increase that reflects on the nature of contests and contesters.

Other possible analyses are limited only by the imagination of the questioner.

Comment: Looks like a good, if depressing result.  Depressing to one whose Morse is a little shaky at 5 wpm...

Comment: @ZeissIkon My advice is to pick up any text and start *sending* it. I've Elmered several hams who quickly increased their CW receiving speed this way.

Comment: Working on that.  At present, the only oscillator I have has an electronic version of a bug key, and the key itself is too light to use easily.  I've got a straight key, but I need to get it wired and the "bug" circuits out of the oscillator.  It's a weekend's work, probably.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Shaky at 5 WPM? Been there, done that! Go to https://www.w0btu.com/links.html and download *The Art & Skill of Radio Telegraphy*. I can personally testify that it is a must-read for anyone who wants to enjoy CW! Also, check out those paid apps at the top. I have a free coupon from the app developer to download those at no charge; email me if you want it.

Comment: @MikeWaters There's a bad case of "too much help" out there re: learning Morse.  If I had time to read all the "help" I get referred to, I'd have time to practice my Morse an hour a day -- and I don't.

Comment: My website www.w0btu.com is down, but *The Art & Skill of Radio Telegraphy* is available as a PDF download, just a Google search away.